# Is there a tool for searching keywords super fast in many pdfs files?

Tags: pdf, search, cache, pdfgrep

I have a bunch of technical books,
and I have been using `pdfgrep` for a while,
but it takes substantial amount of time for searching all.

can somebody recommend me of a cli tool for searching in pdf files super fast?

it should have an underline database for caching purposes - similar to `locate` command but just for pdf's keywords.

Thank you all! :)

Comment: How do you ordinarily use `pdfgrep`? Do you use the `--cache` or `--page-range` options, for example? Or do you often want to find the _first_ match?

Comment: Ohh ! According to my pdfgrep's manual on my system (pdfgrep version 1.4.1), there is no cache option. from which version the cache feature was inserted?

Comment: I was reading the latest manual at https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html  The option seems to have been added in release 2.0

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`pdfgrep`](https://pdfgrep.org/) you can use [`rga`](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all).

`rga` performs a recursive search with caching enabled by default.

I did a quick comparison with a 15 GB PDF collection stored on an SSD.

```
$ gtime --format "%Es" pdfgrep --recursive --cache --ignore-case conclusion
2:15:26s # initial run
3:05.30s # with cache

$ gtime --format "%Es" rga --type pdf conclusion
33:26.96s # initial run
1:18.70s  # with cache

$ gdu -sh --apparent-size ~/.cache/pdfgrep
697M    /Users/sschmidt/.cache/pdfgrep

$ gdu -sh --apparent-size ~/Library/Caches/rga
186M    /Users/sschmidt/Library/Caches/rga
```

So `rga` was about 4x faster than `pdfgrep` on the initial run and about 2x faster on the cached run. Apart from that the size of the `rga` cache was only about a quarter of the `pdfgrep` cache. This if course just my specific setup, so results may vary depending on your configuration.